# How to implement GridLayout in Androidx?

Tags: android, androidx, android-gridlayout

I tried to implement the GridLayout by downloading it directly via android studio but I get this error:

```
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download gridlayout.aar (androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0)
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download gridlayout.aar (androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0)
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

I already tried to set the Global Gradle settings to offline work but a new error is displayed

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download gridlayout.aar (androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0): No cached version available for offline mode
Disable offline mode and sync project
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Is GridLayout not yet available for android Studio?

Here is my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.guessit"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Glide maybe later add code to proguard
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    // circle imageview
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

    // cardview

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see from the warnings, nothing is wrong with gridlayout lib. If you want it to work,  you need to disable **Offline work** from Android Studio. In order to disable it, follow the following steps:

"Gradle is in offline mode, which means that it won't go to the network to resolve dependencies. Go to Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle and uncheck "Offline work". In Android Studio open the settings and search for offline it will find the Gradle category which contains Offline work. You can disable it there."
[image]

Then, you may use the gridlayout

```
 <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Please let me know if it does not work by commenting.

Comment: Yes but then the first error comes, I already tried it. I want to resolve the first error message that I posted